# c++ double pointer array list

Tags: c++

well i need to make a class called TList which have a private attribute and a counter

```
private:
    TPerson **pListe;
     int counter;
```

TPerson is another class i made before. counter is to know the position of the array.
So i need to create a List which have methods like

```
Add(TPerson *p), Delete(TPerson *p)
```

Now my problem is:
how can i add those TPerson objects to my double pointer list?

i've my

```
void TListe::Add(TPerson &p) {...}
```

method.

i tryed it like that:
    pListe[counter] = &p;

for example and it doesnt work.. can somebody explain me how i need to work with double pointer arrays and use them as lists?

greetings

Comment: Can't you simply use ``std::vector``? Sounds like less hassle and it's the recommended approach in your situation, as I'm not sure how you're handling the case when ``counter`` is beyond the last allocated cell within pListe.

Comment: If this is homework, you should add the `[homework]` tag. That lets others know how they should answer (explain, rather than just solving your immediate problem). If it is not homework, then you shouldn't be trying to write a dynamic array data structure in the first place, because it already exists in the standard library.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is it when you build? Runtime crashes? You have allocated the array?

Comment: Why all the pointers? Why not store the objects directly? Why not use a `std::vector`?

Comment: well it's not a homework.. it is a class work :) we haven't worked with vector before.. so i don't think i can use them.

Comment: @darkdog They are a fundamental and essential part of C++. If you haven’t learned them, now is the time. In fact, you should have learned them (long!) before pointers.

Comment: the same applies. The general tag is just `homework`, but it is used to indicate all kinds of schoolwork, as well as self-study. As I said, the important thing about the tag is that it tells answerers that they try to emphasize explanation and help the OP *understand*, rather than just providing a ready-made solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused by your code example , `*pListe` is going to hold pointer to first element of array of `TPerson` objects, or just pointer to `TPerson` ?. I think you you need to first allocate array of pointers to person :

```
pListe = new TPerson* [size];
```

then you can do:

```
Add(TPerson* p) {
pListe[some_counter_to_past_the_last_element] = p;
...
}

Add(TPerson& p) {
pListe[some_counter_to_past_the_last_element] = &p;
...
}
```

Comment: ahhh thank you.. that works. my mistake was that i was using "pListe[some_counter_to_past_the_last_element] = *p;